# Twenty Seventeen - Navigation bar, logo, header size

Tags: child-theme, navigation, theme-twenty-seventeen

I'm new here, like 3 days learning about WordPress, I think is very good, have some problems to understand the CSS, I think I'll get over it with time.

I have a problem maybe someone can help me.

Problem:
[image: Actually]

I want it like this.

[image: Want it]

Thanks in advanced.

[GitHub](https://github.com/fdesur/twentyseventeen-child)

Regards!

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far? Can you please post your development site so we can edit the code via Dev Tools to help provide you a code snippet.

Comment: Hi Liam, the website is milibyte.cl, thanks for the fast reply!, ¿am i clear what i should like to do in the images?
¡They are welcome all the advices!

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `style.css`. Using Flex to align and space the items in the header.

```
#masthead .wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navigation-top a {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: uhmm no change about it. i upgraded style.css

Comment: Please ensure you are linking your stylesheet correctly.

Comment: yes, is working. Thanks!
 something i did wrong, but whatever.
i can't understand the header size css.

Comment: thanks for the initial help, now i need to fix another stuff. see you around!